# RStata Set Stata Binary Path

Tags: r, stata

I am trying to use [RStata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStata/RStata.pdf) in order to run Stata from R. I first did:

```
options("RStata.StataVersion" = 14)
```

That didn't cause an error.

But I also need to set the binary path. I have a Mac, and Stata is contained in a folder in the Applications folder. Here is what I have tried:

```
options("RStata.StataPath" = "/Applications/Stata/Stata")
```

Unfortunately, this causes an error. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe that path is incomplete? I guess it needs a prefix like `.`, `~`, `C:/` or something.

Comment: Sorry for the perhaps stupid question: do you need to have Stata installed to use the RStata package in R?

Answer (score 1):

With no knowledge of RStata, I can say that on macOS 10.12.6 with Stata/SE release 15 installed, in the terminal window

```
open /Applications/Stata/StataSE.app
```

is what's required to launch Stata. It is possible that in looking for the Stata executable, your Finder Preferences does not have "show all filename extensions" set in the Advaced pane, so you weren't shown the .app extension.

Answer (score 0):

From the [README](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStata/README.html), better rendered [here](https://github.com/lbraglia/RStata)

> Mac users are a notable group: at this stage they should set the path
>   for the command line executable (not the GUI app). Eg for a Stata13 SE
>   installation in El Capitain (with default options) the path is
>   '**/Applications/Stata/StataSE.app/Contents/MacOS/stata-se**'. In other
>   cases (Stata licenses, installation path and so on) the path could be
>   slightly different (BTW, i've found the path 'exploring' the
>   filesystem with a terminal, not the graphics explorer since it 'stops'
>   at 'StataSE.app').

(yes, putting something in the manual as well is in my TODO :) )

hth, best, Luca